# Is it a bad idea to dispatch actions from mapDispatchToProps, and why?

Tags: redux, react-router-redux

We are using react-router-redux for routing in our app.

```
<Route path='/users/:userId' component={SomeComponent} />
```

In this way, `SomeComponent` will receive a `userId` in its match params. The problem is that in order for the children of `SomeComponent` to receive the id we must pass it as props from parent to child. As much as possible we try to avoid passing props from parent to child, preferring to use containers and the redux store.

In order to provide the params to children, we are considering having `SomeComponent` dispatch an action when its props change. A convenient way to do this is:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<IState>, props: IPropsFromParent): IPropsFromDispatch => {

  dispatch(ActionCreators.updateShowingUserId({
    userId: props.match.params.userId,
  }))

  return {
    anotherAction: () => {
      dispatch(ActionCreators.doOtherStuff())
    }
  }
}
```

This way, whenever the component receives a new `userId` from the router, it will update the value in the store. Components which render deeper in the tree but which are not themselves connected to the router can use this value for conditional rendering, etc...

However, we are concerned that this may be bad practice for reasons that we are not yet aware of. It is known that calling `setState` in a react component's render function is forbidden. I wonder if there is some similar concrete restriction on calling dispatch in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Is it a bad idea to dispatch actions in mapDispatchToProps, and if so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Since the dispatch will be run every time the redux `store` was updated it (and the props of the component change) wouldn't be a good idea to dispatch something inside the `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` or `mergeProps` functions, since you would overwrite the previous value with a default one. You should add the value you're dispatching to the initial store when possible or dispatch the defaults from the parent which controls the component.

Documentation for [`ReactRedux.connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: In the example code above, you might be surprised to learn that `mapStateToProps` runs twice, while `mapDispatchToProps` only runs once. I suspect that `mapDispatchToProps` is only re-run if props changes, not state.

Comment: Correct. If `mapDispatch` is defined with one arg (`dispatch`), it will be run once when the component is instantiated.  If it's defined with two args (`(dispatch, ownProps)`), it will be run on instantiation, and also whenever the wrapper component's props are updated.

Comment: @markerikson Yeah! So, is there a problem with dispatching actions in `mapDispatch`? Something like "it may cause an infinite loop" or "you shouldn't interrupt the render cycle with updates to state"? I've updated my question with our concrete use case, in case that helps. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm going to downvote your answer: your answer is "it wouldn't be a good idea, ... since you would overwrite the previous value with a default one". This isn't true, so it can't be the answer. Thank you for your effort though!

Comment: PS I suspect that you are right, and that this is a bad idea (that's why I asked in the first place), but I need to know _why_ it is a bad idea in order to decide whether to do it or not.